# Removing spacing under the image

Tags: html, css

***HTML :***

```
<div>
   <img src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/jsbin_16.png" />
</div>
```

***CSS :***

```css
div { border:5px solid #000; }
img { border:1px solid red; }
```

***Issue illustration :***

[image: result]

My problem is the space under the image, I added *black* border to the `div` container and *red* border to the `img` to make it more demonstrative.

***Demo :***

#### [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/wedazira/1/edit)

Comment: You can also set is as a background image for the `div {background: url("http://static.jsbin.com/images/jsbin_16.png") left no-repeat;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to `img` layout, just change it  to `display: block` :

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wedazira/2/edit)

Or change `vertical-align` property to `top`:

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wedazira/12/edit)

Or set `font-size: 0` to the `div` container :

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wedazira/11/edit)

Or set `line-height: 0` to the `div` container :

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wedazira/10/edit)

Comment: ...or `line-height:0`

Comment: `display-block` is more considerable i think.